# How to Include a real-time timer in a cell of a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Been working with data from SQL and show data from datagridview, the project is like an Internet Cafe with real-time timer on it. Been having problem on this one.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DGV_TIMER_TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CONNECTION connect = new CONNECTION();

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        Dictionary<int, Stopwatch> swDct = new Dictionary<int, Stopwatch>();
        int nextID = 0;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect.constring);
            con.Open();

            DT.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string)); // stopwatch # 0
            DT.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));           // id 1  
            DT.Columns.Add("Elapsed", typeof(string)); // 2

            String QUERY = "SELECT tag_no, guardian_name, child_name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(time_in AS TIME), 0) AS TIMEIN ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(time_out AS TIME), 0) AS TIMEOUT , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, time_in ,time_out)AS MINUTES,extended FROM ENTRY_DATA";
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(QUERY, con);
            adapt.Fill(DT);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
        

            foreach (string buttonName in new string[] { "Stop" , "Start"})
            {
                DataGridViewButtonColumn colTemp = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                colTemp.Name = buttonName + "Col";
                colTemp.HeaderText = buttonName;
                colTemp.Width = 50;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colTemp);
            }


            timer1.Tick += (timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 50;
            timer1.Start();

            DT.Rows.Add("Stopwatch #" + nextID.ToString(), nextID, "00:00.00");
            swDct.Add(nextID, new Stopwatch());
            nextID++;

            con.Close();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            foreach (DataRow dRow in DT.Rows)
            {
                string elapsedString = swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.ff");  
              
//PROBLEM: SystemCastValidException
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                dRow["Elapsed"] = elapsedString;
            }
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                Stopwatch swTemp = swDct[(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value];
                switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText)
                {
                    case "Start":
                        swTemp.Start();
                        break;
                    case "Stop":
                        swTemp.Stop();
                        break;
                    case "Reset":
                        swTemp.Reset();
                        break;
                    case "Restart":
                        swTemp.Restart();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the *actual* exception? Post the *entire* exception as text, not just the type name, message or image. An exception's text includes the stack trace that led to it. Right now it's hard to understand which line is the one that actually throws - the line that tried to pull a stopwatch from a dictionary? Or the one that tried to set the DataRow's cell?

Comment: BTW what the code actually does is set a cell to a stopwatch's value, not include a timer in a gridview

Comment: `Stopwatch` is bad idea I guess. What if manager's app will be closed? Time will stop ticking? Guessing that better idea is write to databese active session start time and display just a difference `currentTime - sessionStartTime`. Then if you'll even restart the PC/Server, everyting would be ok. Also support foe pause/resume the session would be helpful with full log. Paid time must be counted carefully. Also time counters must not depend on lical PC clock but on Server time. Local PC clock can be changed by manager, it will break all the calculations.

Comment: Tip: To make easier the app side i suggest to learn about these things: `BindingList<T>` usage, `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation and purpose + `someControl1.DataBindings.Add(...)`, and finally [`async/await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). - It will give you abilities to: 1) interact with data, not with controls, 2) do multiple things at once (that's possible not only with Timer). - Not mandatory but can be highly helpful.

Comment: I will explain it in summary : the code will need to compare the value of DATEDIFF(MINUTE, time_in ,time_out)AS MINUTES to the "Timer" which if it exceeds it will gave a notification or pop up box to the user . Im still exploring stuff might able to deliver . any suggestions guys?

Comment: aepot, Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks for the advice , I'll try to rethink again what approach I will do.

Comment: aepot, Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks for the advice , I'll try to rethink again what approach I will do.